# Reformat a date string with hyphens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python and would like to write clean code from the beginning. I need a parser of a string which formats a date in the form of "20140101" into "2014-01-01". How I achieved this is via:

```
def parse(date):

    list_date = list(date)
    list_date.insert(4,"-")
    list_date.insert(7,"-")
    return "".join(list_date)
```

which works perfectly fine but looks not very clean. Maybe there is no other solution but if there is a more pythonic way to code it would be appreciated if you would share this!

Comment: Have you tried to read the `datetime.strptime` and `datetime.strftime` documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def parse(date):
    return "{}-{}-{}".format(date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:])
```

Might have made a small error, but that should do the trick, given how you're doing this.

See also [pyformat.info](http://pyformat.info) for more information about Python's string formatting.

Also, I suggest looking into the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module for more info about even more Pythonic ways of dealing with dates. ;)

Comment: Probably don't even need the format. `'-'.join` would work as well

Comment: True dat. Just figured `format` would give a few more intuitive options for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format, as mentioned by B. Eckles.  But you can also do:

```
def parse(date):
    return "%s-%s-%s" % (date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:])
```

Using format seems unnecessary as you aren't actually using it for anything more than substituting portions of your string.